# Copy .NET Core authentication cookie to another browser works

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, authorization, cookie-authentication

I have a website project with .NET 6 (MVC) and I use an authentication cookie for authorizing users with this config:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        options.Cookie.Name = "sepsep";
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan=TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
    });
```

I've created the same cookie (name, value and etc) on another browser on another computer and I am authorized now on that other computer!

Is it possible to protect this cookie so it won't be copied? I mean I think this cookie should just work in my own computer and even just in that browser!

**UPDATE**

I use claim based method to login the user:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("UserMobile",mobile),
        };
            
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                         {
                             IsPersistent = true
                         };

_contextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
                                         new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), 
                                         authProperties);
```

Comment: The problem is you can change the IP address of any computer.  So how do you uniquely identify a client that hackers cannot get around.  The best way is not to use a cookie but instead use Windows Credentials to make sure your connection is secure.  Than the cookie doesn't matter.

Comment: how about to use something like unique machine key?

Comment: a cookie should not really be used to secure as a form of access. There are much better things like logins, tokens, auth, and many others.

Comment: Can a hacker get access to the machine key?

Comment: @jdweng I mean something like MAC ID

Comment: The MAC ID is not encrypted and is used in many places that is not encrypted.